# How do I interact with different windows simultaneously using Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome(r"chromedriver.exe")
browser_2 = webdriver.Chrome(r"chromedriver.exe")

browser.get("https://www.seleniumhq.org/")
browser_2.get("https://www.seleniumhq.org/")

browser.find_element_by_id("menu_download").click()
browser_2.find_element_by_id("menu_download").click()
```

Is there a cleaner way to click on the download button in both windows or do I have to repeat the code for each instance of the browser?

I am making a program where I need to insert text, tick boxes ect in several instances of the same website and do not want to have to repeat the same code for each window.

Answer (score 0):

Each browser is a different instance. You can not use a part of the code for both. So the answer is no. You cannot use another to do this. Your above code is correct though.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
path = 'chromedriver.exe'
n_drivers = 2

drivers = [webdriver.Chrome(path) for i in range(n_drivers)]

for driver in drivers:
    driver.get('https://www.seleniumhq.org/')
    driver.find_element_by_id('menu_download').click()
```